# Resizing of slices - whether to check for `len(slice) > 1` or `newCap > 2*len(slice)`

Tags: go, slice

In the [Go Programming Language](https://www.gopl.io/) book, the author gave the following code example of an `append()` function that accepts as arguments a `[]int` and an `int`, and will handle resize accordingly:

```golang
// gopl.io/ch4/append
func appendInt(x []int, y int) []int {
    var z []int
    zlen := len(x) + 1
    if zlen <= cap(x) {
        // There is room to grow. Extend the slice.
        z = x[:zlen]
    } else {
        // There is insufficient space. Allocate a new array.
        // Grow by doubling, for amortized linear complexity.
        zcap := zlen
        if zcap < 2*len(x) { // Question: Why not len(x) > 1?
            zcap = 2 * len(x)
        }
        z = make([]int, zlen, zcap)
        copy(z, x)
    }
    z[len(x)] = y
    return z 
}
```

#### Question

Why is the innermost check written as `if zcap < 2*len(x)` instead of the equivalent `if len(x) > 1`?

The latter appears clearer to me and signals the intention that if the initial slice has length of 0 or 1, we do not allocate additional capacity after appending the new element.

#### Details on Equivalence of `zcap < 2*len(x)` and `len(x) > 1`

We can see that the value of `zcap` is assigned from `zlen`, which in turn has the value `len(x) + 1`, so if we arrange the inequality:

> zcap < 2*len(x)

after substituting `zcap := zlen`, we get:

> zlen < 2*len(x)

after substituting `zlen := len(x) + 1`, we get:

> len(x) + 1 < 2*len(x)

after rearranging, we get:

> len(x) > 1

Comment: `zcap < 2*len(x)` condition makes very little sense to me at all. Practically, you only have one edge case: `len(x) == 0`, everything else can be handled with `newCapacity = len(x) * 2`

Comment: zcap < 2*len(x) is not equivalent to len(x) > 1. Your derivation is wrong as len(x) can be 0. (and possible a lot of other mistakes.)

Comment: @Volker Why zcap < 2*len(x) is not equivalent to len(x) > 1?

Comment: @Volker, the derivation is valid. The code essentially doubles the capacity if len(x)>1, but for some reason, it does it in so many words. Note that at that point, len(x)==cap(x), and it doesn't have to double the capacity only if len(x)=0.

Comment: A, sorry, its not a division by zero. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `zcap < 2*len(x)` is equivalent to `len(x) > 1`. You could totally replace `zcap < 2*len(x)` with `len(x) > 1` in this function.

But according to the source [code](https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/blob/master/ch4/append/main.go#L11), There is another function named `appendslice`. In this function, you couldn't do a replacement.

I think author use `zcap < 2*len(x)` only for keeping two function consistent. The main purpose here is to avoid frequent allocation.